# Azure fails to stop a VM

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, virtual-machine

I'm on a shared MSDN Azure license paid for by my employer.

So, when I try to stop a VM and Azure says "error: unable to stop VM", and I go to submit a tech support request, and it says "Must buy a support plan" does that mean I have to sit and wait for it to eat my credits up?

The VM is running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter on a "basic A1" configuration.  It was working fine, and I logged off and clicked "Stop" from the Azure portal.  It turns red and says it can't stop the VM.

Comment: I would suggest looking into Audit logs to find out why you're getting this error.

Comment: Check the audit log, and find more information about this failure. In the Azure Portal, click **Browse**, type in "audit log", and filter with your Vm name.

Comment: Yeah. Not showing me much at all. No mention of it under Audit Logs.  In the drop down notifications menu it shows a bunch of "Failed to connect to VM" alerts.

Comment: follow-up - closed and reopened the browser windows and was able to stop the VMs.  The alerts were cleared out.  Audit Logs shows nothing at all.  Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Close all browser windows.  Open a new browser session, login and you should be able to connect to the VMs and management them.